# How can design a full screen calendar view in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I need to design a calendar view and I would like to use Twitter Bootstrap since I am used to using it for smaller projects.

But the 12 column span system doesn't seem to fit right on creating a calendar view.

So if I have a row that is span12, and I want to create a sub-row, I need 7 evenly spaced boxes for the calendar.  I can't see how I can do this.

I thought about just creating a span12 and then just applying my own CSS inside it.  Bypassing the Bootstrap system.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you try downloading a **grid-only**, customized to 7 columns, bootstrap ? You may want *Grid system* and *Layout*

Here : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Then you just **add your own selector** in front of the few rules in the style sheet created, and you should have your very own 7 columns grid.

For the fluid grid, if you need it, just be sure that

```
@gridColumns*@fluidGridColumnWidth + (@gridColumns-1)*@fluidGridGutterWidth <= 100
```

The variables you are interested in are

- `@gridColumns` : number of columns
- `@gridColumnWidth` : width of one static column
- `@gridGutterWidth` : width of the space between the static columns
- `@fluidGridColumnWidth` : width of one fluid column
- `@fluidGridGutterWidth` : width of the space between the fluid columns

Total width of a static container will be given as

```
@gridColumns*@gridColumnWidth + (@gridColumns-1)*@gridGutterWidth
```

Enjoy !